# Do I queue with the same people in the RDF when selecting an Instance?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

I'm currently level 31 and I want to do two instances I haven't been able to complete (sadly, due to an incompetent team, like in Gnomeregan).

I know that if I queue for a Random Dungeon, I get a blue bag and the exp, but if I queue for a classic, specific dungeon, I don't.

If I select the instance I want to play, do I queue with the same people than selected random (and can be possibly selected)? Because if that's not like that, it's gonna be REALLY hard to do those instances because of the few people who doesn't use RDF.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have to queue with the same people, but you can.

If you choose a specific (we'll say Gnomeregan) you will get put into the queue for that specific dungeon. Other players that queued up for "Random" can be selected into your queue even though you queued up specific. The only downside of doing the specific is not receiving the bonus bag and experience.

If you queue up for a random, you will eventually get the dungeon that is not complete on the current list of dungeons that are available at your level. This is the way I go since you get bonus loot and experience every time, however the choice is yours. :)

To tell which dungeons are your level, or can be selected in the random queue, open your dungeon finder UI and click specific dungeons. This will give the list of the possible dungeons you can encounter.

Not all level tiers have the following setup, some only have Red/Yellow dungeons:

> Red - "Hard" dungeon. A little above your current level.
>
> Yellow - "Medium" dungeon. Currently at the right level.
>
> Green - "Easy" dungeon. A little below your current level.

Comment: That was my train of thought (because I wanted the experience, the bag, and the quests for Gnomeregan), but yesterday I did Scarlet Monastery 5 times in a row and the hope was lost =( - how do I know it's for my level? Only yellow-red dungeons?

Comment: To tell which dungeons are your level, or can be selected in the random queue, open your dungeon finder UI and click specific dungeons. This will give the list of the possible dungeons you can encounter. Sometimes it does certain ones over and over (I'm not certain why). If you have any friends that are a little bit lower of a level, try to invite them in to your party and queue up for a random, it could pop Gnomeregan for you.

Comment: Whether a dungeon is complete or not has no effect on the queue - if you are locked to an instance and queue random there is every chance you can get the instance you are locked to...

Answer (score 0):

The dungeon finder considers all queue'd players when assembling a group.  Players that queue for specific dungeons may be matched with players that queue for random dungeons.  Since it is easiest to match players that queue randomly, those players get a random dungeon queue reward for making the finder's matching work easier.

Example:

- I queue specifically for Gnomeregan.
- The dungeon finder looks in the queue for players that have compatible choices with Gnomeregan.
- It finds 1 more that queue'd specifically and 3 more than queue'd randomly.  The group is formed.
- When the dungeon runs completes, those 3 players that queue'd randomly get the random dungeon rewards.